# Unable to execute multiple stored procedures in the parent stored procedure Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Iam new to Snowflake so this question might be very silly but iam unable to resolve this issue,
I have 2 child procs child1 and Child2 which are called from a Parent procedure, the issue is only one child proc is getting executed, whichever is called first and skips the other procedure.

```
create or replace procedure parent_prc(P_SRC_DB varchar,P_TGT_DB varchar)
  returns varchar
  language javascript
  as     
  $$ 
    var some_sql_cmd = "TRUNCATE TABLE "+P_SRC_DB+".schema_a.table1"
    var some_sql_stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: trunc_prestg_cmd} );
    var child1_proc_exec_cmd = "call 
   "+P_TGT_DB+".schema_a.child1_proc('"+P_SRC_DB+"','"+P_TGT_DB+"')"
    var child1_proc_stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: child1_proc_exec_cmd} )
    var child2_proc_exec_cmd = "call 
    "+P_TGT_DB+".schema_a.child2_proc('"+P_SRC_DB+"','"+P_TGT_DB+"')"
    var child2_proc_stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: child2_proc_exec_cmd} )
    
  try
    {
        child1_proc_stmt.execute();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
    return(" Error :"+err);
    }
    
    try
    {
       child2_proc_stmt.execute();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
    return(" Error :"+err);
    }

    try
    {           
        some_sql_stmt.execute();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
    return("Truncate Error :"+err);
    }
 $$
```

It executes Child1_proc and directly goes some_sql_stmt execution and Child2_proc is not executed, if i remove child1_proc, the Child2_proc  is executed, iam not sure what is the issue, please help..

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the child1_proc is successful?  You should also see an error in the parent_prc call.  If you look in query history for the session id (use: select current_session(); to get session id), you can see all queries executed by the stored procedure and it should help identify the issue.

In the example provided above, the below part will have a syntax error, but this wouldn't allow the procedure to compile.  (some_sql_cmd should be trunc_prestg_cmd)

```
var some_sql_cmd = "TRUNCATE TABLE "+P_SRC_DB+".schema_a.table1"
var some_sql_stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: trunc_prestg_cmd} 
);
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, there are no errors in child1_proc, infact it does its job, the issue is the child_proc2 is getting skipped, further more if i comment the calling of Child1_proc, then it executes the Child2 Proc successfully, if both procs are put it executes the first proc and skips the second proc and goes down to execute sql statement.

Comment: Hi Raghu, thanks for the feedback.  This example is not behaving in that manner, can you please log a support case and provide the relevant query id's so we can further evaluate this behavior and provide guidance?  https://community.snowflake.com/s/login/